# Is there a way to have a Google Form response trigger the creation of a new Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I do not have any experience with apps script. Something I am trying to learn currently and this is my first project that I will be working towards.

My company that I work for use a mundane spreadsheet which is used as our purchase document. I have translated it to a Google Sheet that looks like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mZlzeu9-9Mb0B1VmlNSJDfCxELqci4KRc_HFbRt3NwM/edit?usp=sharing

Currently, anyone that makes a purchase needs to fill out this spreadsheet and send along a copy of the receipt of the purchase via email to our billing person.

The Google Form I want to create to streamline this will contain basic information like the name of the person filling it out and an email address. I would add some of the items below along with a Google Drive Upload so that the person can upload a picture of the receipt(s).

What I would want to have happen is on a Google Form response, I would like apps script to do the following, in this order:

1. Create a copy of the spreadsheet linked above and Title it as "[Team Name] [Date] Credit Card Request"
2. Fill it with the information that is needed:

- Date of Transaction
- Amount Request
- Vendor Name
- Program Name (I think this can be done away with because of Team)
- Team

3. When the spreadsheet is filled out, I would like to then email the billing person a completed XLSX copy along with the file attachments that were uploaded for that response.
   3a. Sending a copy of the same email to the person filling out the form originally would be a plus.

Because of the format of this spreadsheet, when the team is specified, I am hoping I can have the Apps Script set the value of the corresponding cell for that team (a checkbox) to TRUE.

I may ask for some assistance with this later on, but I am wondering, **is this possible to do? **

My apologies, I do not have any script experience, not sure where to even start.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What you are asking can be done with Apps Script, but you may want to try [AutoCrat](https://cloudlab.newvisions.org/autocrat) instead of writing your own code. For other options, choose **Extensions > Add-ons > Get add-ons** and search for  `mail merge`.

Comment: This is all pretty standard staff, but it seems like you haven't tried anything yet. When asking a question here, make sure to show the research you did, what you've tried and where you got stuck. If you need something done from scratch, you rprobably want to go to Upwork instead.

Comment: Ok, I assume that the answer is a yes, it can be done. Thank you